# Does this apply: $\sin^2(\pi t-\pi) + \cos^2(\pi t-\pi) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

So I'm solving for the length of the following parametric description:

$$
\Bigg[x(t)=3\cos(\pi t-\pi)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y(t)=3\sin(\pi t - \pi)$$
I applied the formula for solving for length, namely:
$$\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{(-3\pi \sin(\pi t - \pi))^2+(3\pi \cos(\pi t - \pi))^2 }\,\,\, dt$$
$$\int_{0}^{2} \sqrt{9\pi^2\times1}\,\,\, dt$$

My question is:
Is it correct that [ $(\sin(\pi t - \pi))^2+ (\cos(\pi t - \pi))^2 = 1$ ] because of the rule: $\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$ ? Can I always apply this convention as long as I have the same on the inside of the sin and cos?

Highly appreciated,

-Bowser

Comment: Yes. The rule applies for *any* value of the argument, including complex ones.

Comment: @Joanpemo thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice:

- $$3\cos(\pi t-\pi)=-3\cos(\pi t)$$
- $$3\sin(\pi t-\pi)=-3\sin(\pi t)$$

  ---

Now:

- For the integrand part:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(-3\cos(\pi t)\right)^2+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(-3\sin(\pi t)\right)^2}=\sqrt{9\pi^2\sin^2(\pi t)+9\pi^2\cos^2(\pi t)}=$$
$$\sqrt{9\pi^2\left[\sin^2(\pi t)+\cos^2(\pi t)\right]}=\sqrt{9\pi^2}\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)+\cos^2(\pi t)}=$$
$$3\pi\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)+\cos^2(\pi t)}$$

Now, know that for any value of $x$, we have the identity $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$, and notice $b>a$:

$$3\pi\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)+\cos^2(\pi t)}\space\text{d}t=3\pi\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1}\space\text{d}t=3\pi\int_{a}^{b}1\space\text{d}t=3\pi\left[t\right]_{a}^{b}=3\pi\left(b-a\right)$$

And in your example $a=0$ and $b=2$:

$$\text{I}=3\pi\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)+\cos^2(\pi t)}\space\text{d}t=3\pi\left(2-0\right)=6\pi$$

Comment: Very thorough answer. Thanks for that!

Comment: @Bowser You're more than welcome!!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is, the relation $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$ holds for any $x$ value

Answer (score -1):

Hint you can verify using formulae $$\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$$ and $$cos(a-b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)$$